# How to to show the popup when recover data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I would like show the popup when recover data or refresher page in reactjs using hook

1. open page, do not show popup
2. fill in form, not submit, only fill fields
3. close page or reload page
4. open page again
5. show popup want to recover data
6. data is recover

How can I make them ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your state as a JSON string to localstorage on [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event.

```js
import React from "react";

const saveState = (state) => {
  localStorage.setItem("yourKey", JSON.stringify({
      time: Date.now(),
      data: state
    })
  );
};

const loadState = () => {
  const str = localStorage.getItem("yourKey");
  if (str == null) return null;
  const obj = JSON.parse(str);
  if (obj.time > Date.now() + 60000) //Date.now() returns time in miliseconds
    return null; //stored data is too old
  return obj.data;
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(loadState() || {
      name: "",
      another: ""
    }
  );

  const handleData = React.useCallback(() => {
    saveState(data);
  }, [data]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleData, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleData);
  }, [handleData]);

  return (
    <div>
      Name
      <input
        value={data.name}
        onChange={(e) => setData((p) => ({ ...p, name: e.target.value }))}
      />
      Another
      <input
        value={data.another}
        onChange={(e) => setData((p) => ({ ...p, another: e.target.value }))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the data somewhere, for example in local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

The data in React states does not persist when you reload or close the page.